# Magento isn't displaying custom block

Tags: magento, layout, block

In my config.xml I have:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Quickorder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Quickorder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <quickorder>
                <rewrite>
                    <quickorder>Test_Quickorder_Block_Quickorder</quickorder>
                </rewrite>
            </quickorder>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quickorder>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Quickorder</module>
                    <frontName>quickorder</frontName>
                </args>
            </quickorder>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quickorder>
                    <file>quickorder.xml</file>
                </quickorder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In app/code/community/Test/Quickorder/controllers/IndexController.php I have:

```
<?php
class Test_Quickorder_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout(array('default');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/quickorder.xml I have:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                <label>Quick Order</label>
                <url>quickorder</url>
                <title>Quick Order</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>1</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <quickorder_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="quickorder/quickorder" name="quick" template="quickorder/quickorder.phtml"/>
        </reference>          
    </quickorder_index_index>
</layout>
```

In app/design/frontend/base/default/template/quickorder/quickorder.phtml I have:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

And in app/code/community/Test/Quickorder/Block/Quickorder I have:

```
<?php
class Test_Quickorder_Block_Quickorder extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{

}
```

I was expecting "Hello" to show up right in the middle of the page. Instead I get nothing. I know some part of the layout is working because when I navigate to quickorder I get

```
<body class="quickorder-index-index">
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to where I've gone wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't examined all your code, but this

```
class Test_Quickorder_Block_Quickorder extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{

}
```

should be this

```
class Test_Quickorder_Block_Quickorder extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

If you want a block to render a template, it needs to be, or inherit from, `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had combined your tutorial with another one and after your recommendation it now works perfectly.